# How do I fix a microphone problem in Skype?

Tags: audio, microphone, skype

I have a problem that my voice sounds stutterred or certain bits are skipped when using Skype.

I found the solution here:

https://superuser.com/questions/728164/skype-cutting-out-and-skipping-my-voice

but I can't find the option of removing the ambient noise cancellation anywhere on my mac! Reading about it on the web, it seems like it was removed from the newer macOS.

How can I then fix the problem, which seems to come from that "feature" of canceling ambient noise?